# How to reliably monitor drives mount/umount on linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I've found a few similar questions here but none of them works now.

Monitoring (inotify) of `/etc/mtab` is not working because it's symling to `/proc/mounts` now. Monitoring via `udisks` doesn't catch manually mount/umounted drives. Netlink sockets also don't work (no mount/umount actions).

So what's the really working way to monitor mounts and umounts?

P.S.
I don't care about namespaced mounts, just global.

Comment: `/etc/mtab` is unreliable anyway since you can `mount -n`. I'd say the only way is to use kernel-level tracing on mount syscalls... Not sure how you can do this though.

Comment: Can you monitor /proc/mounts?

Comment: @Dave problem is, with recent Linux distributions, /proc/mounts is a symlink to self/mounts...

Comment: @fge, then, can you monitor /proc/self/mounts?

Comment: @Dave this won't tell you if processes using _another_ namespace mount/unmount something, though, which is why it is so difficult :/

Answer (score 3):

I believe that [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) should probably be usable to monitor mounts.

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor /proc/mounts without polling. Put it in the exceptfds list to select, and
then seek to the beginning of the file every time. Here's a quick demo in python but it should be  easily translatable to C:

```
f = open("/proc/mounts")
while True:
    r,w,x = select.select([],[],[f])
    f.seek(0)
    print f.read()
```